# which is faster orderyBy lodash or ORDER BY in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, lodash, bookshelf.js, knex.js

Which will be the good approach querying a database with ORDER BY or get unorderd data from database and then use orderBy method of lodash?

Comment: Why don't you time it? But rule of the thumb is: large resultsets are sorted faster in a database, plus in certain cases the ordering also affects the resultset (e.g. get top N records) so you must do those in the database. In case of smaller dataset it may be faster to sort them on the client side.

Comment: If you're simply retrieving records from a table, and have built a suitable index that covers your query, the database already has the results in sorted order and can return them immediately without any additional sorting cost.

Comment: Thanks guyz for the suggestions